# Quotes and Word wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, quotes, word-wrap

I am trying to put some text along with quotes in a DIV like this

"All is well that ends well"

now the text is dynamically generated and I am using javascript font replacement plugin (CUFON) for quotes around the text, sometime ending quote drops down to next line because of word wrapping like this

"All is well that ends well
"

How can I prevent that? I couldn't find a way to prevent it. code looks something like that

```
$("#q1").html('<span class="blue_quotes">“ </span>');
$("#ct1").html($.trim(commentText)+'<span class="blue_quotes">” </span>');
```

I added span tags for quotes because I need different font and color for quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use **escape sequence \**  for such cases .. 
But I prefer using unicodes for such cases..

If you want to use the first approach try this

```
$("#q1").html('<span class="blue_quotes"> \“ </span>');
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gqke8/)**

Comment: quotes are showing up fine, the problem is that sometimes the end quote drops down to next line. you can see example at  http://topwritings.com/quote.jpg

Comment: That seems to be because of the lack of space in the div.. Check if the same thing happens after increasing the width of the div??

Comment: but I need to keep fix width, also text inside DIV is dynamic, it changes after every 30 seconds (length of text can increase or decrease)